# App Engine BackendService raising of my exceptions as errors

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, logging

I am logging *endpoints.NotFoundException* as warning then re-raise it and my log is full of errors from */_ah/spi/BackendService.logMessages* which makes it difficult to search actual errors. So i get the same event logged twice. First my code logs it as a warning and then *BackendService* logs it as an error. I was not able to find the usage of *BackendService* class in my code so i do not know how to disable it. So my question is: how do i disable *BackendService* logging or make it not log my exceptions?

Comment: Imho, disabling logging for the BackendService would be a mistake (possible epic fail). It is natural that all uncaught exceptions will be logged. So if you log and re-raise an exception that is exactly the expected and intended behavior. If you disable the logging of uncaught exceptions you have no diagnostic tools whatsoever if an exception occurs that you didn't think of catching.

Comment: yes, i've got your point but my code looks like try-except-raise and nothing else. I don't need to see NotFound 404 as errors in my log

Comment: And BTW, errors will still be logged in endpoints.